# React Native: How to navigate back in inner StackNav on tab bar press from outer TabNav?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator, react-tabs

I'm building a React Native app using *TabNavigator* and *StackNavigator*.

- I'm using *TabNavigator* at the root level of my React Native app.
- Each route inside the *TabNavigator* maps to a *StackNavigator*.
- Each *StackNavigator* has *n* number of screens.

Let's assume I'm on the *Settings Tab* and I'm 3 screens deep in *user settings -> payment options -> credit card 1*.

Each time I tap on the *Settings Tab* I want to go back one screen.

- Tap 1: *credit card 1 -> payment options*
- Tap 2: *payment options -> user settings*
- Tap 3: *user setting -> settings*

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The key is dispatching the proper *navigation action* inside your route's `tabBarOnPress` method if your *stack view*'s route index is not 0.

[image]

---

**index.js**

```
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { Component } from 'react'
import MyTabNavigator from './components/MyTabNavigator'

class MyApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyTabNavigator/>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

**MyTabNavigator.js**

```
import HomeStackNav from './HomeStackNav'
import SettingsStackNav from './SettingsStackNav'

const goBackNavigationAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  action: NavigationActions.back()
})

const routeConfig = {
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStackNav,
    path: 'home',
    navigationOptions: {...}
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsStackNav,
    path: 'settings',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'settings',
      tabBarLabel: 'settings',
      tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
        jumpToIndex(scene.index)
        if (scene.route.index > 0) {                  // <----- this is
          navigation.dispatch(goBackNavigationAction) // <----- where the
        }                                             // <----- magic happens
      }
    })
  }
}

const tabNavigatorConfig = {...}

export default TabNavigator(routeConfig, tabNavigatorConfig)
```